# PHP - PhpStorm - Code style reformat, keep if-statement in one line

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, code-formatting

I have a question about the code style of PhpStorm IDE. I am a fan of using braces for one line `if` statements but I can't get the settings right. When reformatting the code, everything between and including the braces get reformatted to new lines.

**Code before reformat:**

```
if (!$var) {return false;}
```

**Code after reformat:**

```
if (!$var) {
            return false;
}
```

**Desired outcome after reformat (same as before reformat):**

```
if (!$var) {return false;}
```

Can anyone help me get the settings right so I get the desired outcome after a reformat of the code?

P.S. I have tried the following setting and it works for an if-statement without braces:

- Preferences > Editor > Code Style > PHP
- Wrapping and Braces > Control statement in one line (checked)

Comment: Never use the syntax you like.
This code is less readable. Also, it cannot be debugged normally.

Comment: @BramJanssen 1) Do you know that you can edit the preview area on the Code Style pages (so you can preview the changes right away)? Try it. 2) Sadly I could not find the right combination for your case. Accordingly to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9428 it should actually work (my understanding)... 3) I totally agree with AlexBlack -- such one liner is very hard to read: use new lines after `{` and before `'}` -- much easier for the eye and brain, especially for another person/that uses PSR-12 or alike (a common thing).